# Soap message retrieval

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws, message

We are implementing one JAX-WS Web services which requires to retrieve the username and password in SOAP header elements and use those for further use/processing. 
When we are retrieving username/password it’s coming as null. Please help.

```
  if (Boolean.FALSE.equals(context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY))) {      
             try {
                 SOAPMessage sm = context.getMessage();
                 //SOAPEnvelope envelope = context.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
                 SOAPEnvelope envelope = sm.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
                 SOAPHeader sh = envelope.getHeader();

                System.out.println("Message: "+envelope);
                System.out.println("Envelope: "+envelope);
                 System.out.println("Header: "+sh.toString());
                 Iterator it = sh.examineAllHeaderElements();
                 while(it.hasNext()){
                     System.out.println(it.next());
                 }

           String username;
            username = sh.getAttribute("Username");
           // username  = sh.getAttributeValue("Username");
            //String password =  sh.getAttribute("Password");
                 System.out.println("uid:"+username);
                 //System.out.println("pass: "+password);
                context.put("Username", username);
                //context.put("Passsword", password);
                // default scope is HANDLER (i.e., not readable by SEI
                // implementation)
                context.setScope("Username", MessageContext.Scope.APPLICATION);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) { 
    try { 
        SOAPMessage message = context.getMessage(); 
        SOAPHeader header = message.getSOAPHeader();             
        if (header != null) { 
            Iterator i = header.getChildElements();
            //Navigate through header elements to get the username and password
        } 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        //Handle exception 
    } 
    return true; 
}
```

**See also:**

- [Working with Headers in JAX-WS SOAPHandlers](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/Post/Working-with-Headers-in-JAX-WS-SOAPHandlers.aspx)

Comment: Sample<S:Header>
     <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">                             
          <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">                             
               <wsse:Username>TestUser</wsse:Username>
               <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">TestPassword</wsse:Password>
          </wsse:UsernameToken>
     </wsse:Security>
</S:Header>

Comment: Then your message doesn't contain header at all. Are you sure that header is where it supposed to be?

Comment: Actually  the username and password are not attributes of the soap header element (they are nested elements ).